# HTML Drop down value not getting in PHP while sending mail

Tags: php, forms, email, newline, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble getting data passed from drop down menus to sit correctly in an email body. A clip of what I have is below:

```
$primary = $_POST['primary'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$market = $_POST['market'];

$body = "Primary Business Interest: $primary \n".
        "Type of Business: $type \n".
        "Primary Market Segment: $market \n";
```

I've obviously ommited other parts but the email sends just fine but the drop down menus that make up the body seem to ignore the "\n" parameter and just fall into one long string.

I've look over the internet for the past hour trying to find users with the same problem but can't.

Anyone got any ideas I can try?

Comment: the way it is displayed would depend on the client, eg on windows you'll need to use \r\n

Comment: Are you sending HTML email or plaintext?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending a plain text or an html email?

If it's an html one use `<br />` tag to break the lines, otherwise use `\r\n`, I think that it should do it!

Comment: I'll give that a go. Well \n works for other fields, it's just the drop down menus that cause the issue. I'll give it a go now

Comment: false alarm it turns out, Outlook was removing the line breaks for the drop down menus. Apologies for wasting your time!